# Open explorer.exe (desktop) when I click button (Visual Studio)

Tags: winforms

Normally **explorer.exe** starts with Windows.
I want **when Windows starts** to run My Form Application (myform.exe) instead.
**And when I click a button on myform.exe** then I can run explorer.exe (desktop).
How can I do it?

---

Regedit: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`
Here I wrote myform.exe instead of explorer.exe. My program runs but when I click the button it launches My Computer folder, not desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` on your button click event? If so, then add your desktop as an argument, like this:

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"%USERPROFILE%\desktop");`